# Glippy stores clipboard but can't access it

Tags: glippy

After a few hours from the login, Glippy stops working. It still receive input from the clipboard, storing everything highlighted or copied, but when I try to recover an older clipboard item by selecting it from the dropdown menu, it doesn't work.

I don't know where to look for logs/debugging so if you have any suggestion on how to investigate further please comment and I'll add more details to the question.

Comment: Glippy installed from where and how - or do you mean Glipper from the repo's?

Comment: I recommend you file a bug with them.